# What's wrong with the current value of my $PATH?

Tags: path

I am surprised to see the result of my `echo $PATH` while I was in a flutter installation step:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Applications/flutter/bin

I probably made a mistake when installing python 3.9 in 'sudo' before.

What's your point of vue?

Note: SHELL -zsh OS: Catalina

Answer (score 0):

What was wrong was that I was too ignorant to understand the function of this PATH. Now that I knew a little bit more about it, my path was not strange at all.
:D

You will notice that many developers use this kind of obvious variable but without really understanding them, the levels of involvement, or their exact role within the system. They simply use them, thinking: "I add the path to this variable to access my app. That's good, it works. That's it."